# Gettext fallbacks don't work with untranslated strings

Tags: python, gettext, fallback

In source code of my application I wrapped with gettext strings in russian, so this is my default language and *.po files based on it.
Now I need to make fallbacks chain - string that doesn’t translated in **spanish** catalog should be searched in **english** catalog and than if it doesn’t translated will be returned itself in **russian**.

I trying to do this with **add_fallback** method, but untranslated strings in **self._catalog** of **GNUTranslations(NullTranslations)** already replaced with itself and **ugettext** method never doing fallbacks.

What I am doing wrong?

Example:

Current locale is Spanish, and we’ve got no translations for string "Титул должен быть уникальным" in Spanish catalog and as a result "Title should be unique" from English catalog should be returned.

Spanish *.po file

```
msgid "Титул должен быть уникальным"
msgstr "" # <— We've got no translation for this string
```

English *.po file

```
msgid "Титул должен быть уникальным"
msgstr "Title should be unique"
```

Russian *.po file does not contains translations, because this language used as keys in source code (default language)

```
msgid "Титул должен быть уникальным"
msgstr ""
```

I’ve got Spanish translator (object of GNUTranslations), and I add English traslator (object of GNUTranslations) as fallback for it with add_fallback method.
So, my es_translator._fallback is en_translator object.

In **ugettext** function we trying to get value from **self._catalog** by message as key, and only if it is missing we doing **self._fallback** call.
But self._catalog.get(message) for untranslated string return string itself.
`self._catalog["Титул должен быть уникальным"] -> "Титул должен быть уникальным"` and we never doing search in English catalog.

```
def add_fallback(self, fallback):
    if self._fallback:
        self._fallback.add_fallback(fallback)
    else:
        self._fallback = fallback

def ugettext(self, message):
        missing = object()
        tmsg = self._catalog.get(message, missing)
        if tmsg is missing:
            if self._fallback:
                return self._fallback.ugettext(message)
            return unicode(message)
        return tmsg
```

However if message marked as fuzzy it does’t include in self._catalog and fallback works well.

```
#, fuzzy
msgid "Отсутствуют файлы фотографий"
msgstr "Archivos de fotos ausentes"
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. Could you please provide a minimal example?

Comment: Thank you for attention, I tried to explain my pain :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, python is doing something different from the standard fallback mechanism for added functionality which is not working like you think it should. This may warrant a bug report.

The standard fallback mechanism only has one fall back if a string is not in a translation: use the source string. In most cases this is english (the C or POSIX locale forces no lookups), but in your case because the messages in the source the C locale has russian text (which may cause other problems because sometimes the C locale assumes ascii not utf8). The current recommended best practice is to use english in the C locale encoded in seven bit ascii and then translate to all other languages. This is a significant redesign (and admittedly anglocentric) but unless someone improves the tools (which would be even more significant redesign) this is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Of course we made a mistake when choose russian as basic key language but now we've got a lot of source code and 6 catalogs with translations on different languages and now it's a problem to replay. Trying to find alternative solution.

Comment: This is a case where source filtering may be a solution. that is write a program to translate the source code while copying it. If you need help with that, I have done it before. If it is an open source project send me a link, and I will do it. If it is closed source and want me to do it for you I would be willing if paid.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to solve it was removing untranslated strings while compiling *.mo files.
Patch babel/messages/mofile.py write_mo with

```
messages = [m for m in messages if m.string]
```